# QEMU/KVM REDHAT не работает сеть

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel

Здравствуйте!

Установил QEMU/KVM гостевая ОС windows server 2012R2
Основная REDHAT Desktop 7

Не работает сеть, только пингуется.

Интернет в виртуалке QEMU NAT.

Файрволлы в основной ОС выключены
sudo service iptables stop
sudo service firewalld stop

причем сначала вроде работало, но я менял какие-то настройки в основной REDHAT и перестало работать.

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: RedHat ответ не присылает в QEMU. Создаю запрос в виртуалке ping advcash.com

Comment: sudo tcpdump -i wlp2s0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:19:33.627809 IP 192.168.122.95 > 199.83.130.2.ip.incapdns.net: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 70, length 40
10:19:33.628473 IP localhost.localdomain.47220 > gateway.domain: 43653+ PTR? 2.130.83.199.in-addr.arpa. (43)
10:19:33.639250 IP gateway.domain > localhost.localdomain.47220: 43653 1/0/0 PTR 199.83.130.2.ip.incapdns.net. (85)
10:19:33.639788 IP localhost.localdomain.35067 > gateway.domain:

Comment: sudo tcpdump -i virbr0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on virbr0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:23:37.005996 ARP, Request who-has localhost.localdomain tell 192.168.122.95, length 28
10:23:37.006018 ARP, Reply localhost.localdomain is-at 52:54:00:cf:36:4d (oui Unknown), length 28
10:23:37.006170 IP 192.168.122.95.64767 > localhost.localdomain.domain: 17756+ A? advcash.com. (29)
10:23:37.035315 IP localhost.localdomain.domain > 192.168.122.95.64767: 17756 2/2/2 A 199.83.130.2, A 149.126.72.2 (145)

Comment: Как ответ в QEMU прислать ?

Comment: добавь это всё к вопросу в удобоваримом виде [есть кнопка править], а ещё заодно и команду запуска qemu...